# PHP Delete Query for specific records

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

how this is possible to delete Specific records from table like if I have records in my table.

e.g .. Output

```
Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday

IT     | IT      | IT
```

when I delete IT form any day all IT deleted from all days ,,, I only want to delete records on which I click for del.

This is my query structure:

```
<div style="float:left; width: 134px;">
      <?php
         $sql="SELECT * FROM tb_assignment_en,tb_category WHERE tb_assignment_en.enrolled_to = $log_id AND tb_assignment_en.cat_id = tb_category.cat_id AND tb_assignment_en.day = 'Monday' ";

$sql_resource=mysql_query("$sql") or die("Db Error: ".mysql_error());


$rec=mysql_num_rows($sql_resource);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_resource)){ 
?>

    <div class="first" style="width:132px; height:30px; border:1px solid #B6B5B5; margin-right: 1px; margin-bottom: 1px; text-align:center; line-height:2;" ><?php echo "<a href='javascript:del_confirmation(". $row['cat_id'] .")' Title='Delete'>";?><?php echo $row['cat_name']; ?></a></div>
     <?php } ?>
     &nbsp;
</div>
```

Comment: Give full explanation that how you structured the database? The above are not enough for an answer.

Comment: You need to have some kind of unique id on the row you want to delete

Comment: yes I upload my table pic but i'm new user in stackover flow so he not give me Permission to upload picture...

Comment: Dont use Mysql extension, your mysqli , as mysql is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You will need a uniquie id for a table and if you want to delete for example from Monday column then you have to run a update query :-

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET Monday = '' WHERE id = 'your_unique_id';
```

**EDIT :-**

```
UPDATE tb_assignment_en SET Monday = '' WHERE cat_id='".$limo_id."' AND enrolled_to = '".$log_id."'
```

Comment: for example IT in my table are different records when I delete IT from day Monday all IT records del from table ,, I only want to record in Monday which I choose for del.

Comment: This is my SELECT query ...

$sql="SELECT * FROM tb_assignment_en,tb_category WHERE tb_assignment_en.enrolled_to = $log_id AND tb_assignment_en.cat_id = tb_category.cat_id AND tb_assignment_en.day = 'Monday' ";

Comment: this link is for delete records

 <div class="first" style="width:132px; height:30px; border:1px solid #B6B5B5; margin-right: 1px; margin-bottom: 1px; text-align:center; line-height:2;" ><?php echo "<a href='javascript:del_confirmation(". $row['cat_id'] .")' Title='Delete'>";?><?php echo $row['cat_name']; ?></a></div>

Comment: @UmerIshtiaq what you have written in javascript for del_confirmation() function ?? did you write any query such as DELETE FROM table etc...

Comment: ::: Delete query :::
====================================================
$limo_id=$_REQUEST["cat_id"];
$log_id=$_REQUEST["reg_id"];
$sql="delete from tb_assignment_en where cat_id='".$limo_id."' AND enrolled_to = '".$log_id."' ";

Comment: so you can do like this :- UPDATE tb_assignment_en SET Monday = '' WHERE  cat_id='".$limo_id."' AND enrolled_to = '".$log_id."'. You cannot delete a row since you have to remove a content from a column. Instead of delete you should update a column with empty data

Comment: @UmerIshtiaq any progress ?